# How to make an efficient query for extracting enteries of all days in a database in sets?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a database that includes 440 days of several series with a sampling time of 5 seconds. There is also missing data.

I want to calculate the daily average. The way I am doing it now is that I make 440 queries and do the averaging afterward. But, this is very time consuming since for every query the whole database is searched for related entries. I imagine there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

I am doing this in python, and I am just learning sql. Here's the query section of my code:

```
time_cur = date_begin
Data  = numpy.zeros(shape=(N, NoFields - 1))
X     = []
nN    = 0
while time_cur<date_end:
    X.append(time_cur)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM os_table \
                WHERE EXTRACT(year  from datetime_)=%s\
                AND   EXTRACT(month from datetime_)=%s\
                AND   EXTRACT(day   from datetime_)=%s",\
                (time_cur.year, time_cur.month, time_cur.day));

    Y = numpy.array([0]*(NoFields-1))

    n = 0.0
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break
        Y = Y + numpy.array(row[1:])
    Data[nN][:] = Y/n
    nN = nN + 1        
    time_cur = time_cur + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

And, my data looks like this:

```
datetime_,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14
2012-11-13-00:07:53,42,30,0,0,1,9594,30,218,1,4556,42,1482,42
2012-11-13-00:07:58,70,55,0,0,2,23252,55,414,2,2358,70,3074,70
2012-11-13-00:08:03,44,32,0,0,0,11038,32,0,0,5307,44,1896,44
2012-11-13-00:08:08,36,26,0,0,0,26678,26,0,0,12842,36,1141,36
2012-11-13-00:08:13,33,26,0,0,0,6590,26,0,0,3521,33,851,33
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks

Iman

Comment: Could you post some rows from the "os_table"? It would help you to get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the np function so I don't understand what are you averaging. If you show your table and the logic to get the average...

But this is how to get a daily average for a single column

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect('host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    select
        datetime::date as day,
        avg(c1) as c1_average,
        avg(c2) as c2_average
    from os_table
    where datetime between %s and %s
    group by 1
    order by 1
    ''',
    (time_cur, date_end)
);

rs = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()

for day in rs:
    print day[0], day[1], day[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It just works fine. So, do I need to repeat this for every column or is there a way to do it for all of the columns at once?

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses SQL Server syntax - I am not sure how different PostgreSQL is - it should be fairly similar, you may find things like the DATEADD, DATEDIFF and CONVERT statements are different, (Actually, almost certainly the CONVERT statement - just convert the date to a varchar instead -I am just using it as a reportName, so it not vital)  You should be able to follow the theory of this, even if the code doesn't run in PostgreSQL without tweaking.

First Create a Reports Table ( you will use this to link to the actual table you want to report on )

```
CREATE TABLE Report_Periods (
    report_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    report_start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    report_end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT date_ordering
        CHECK (report_start_date <= report_end_date)
)
```

Next populate the report table with the dates you need to report on, there are many ways to do this - the method I've chosen here will only use the days you need, but you could create this with all dates you are ever likely to use, so you only have to do it once.

```
INSERT INTO Report_Periods (report_name, report_start_date, report_end_date)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DatePartOnly], 0) AS DateName,  
    [DatePartOnly] AS StartDate, 
    DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(dd,1,[DatePartOnly])) AS EndDate
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, datetime_), 0) AS [DatePartOnly]
        FROM os_table ) AS M
```

Note in SQL server, the smallest time allowed is 3 milliseconds - so the above statement adds 1 day, then subtracts 3 milliseconds to create a start and end datetime for a day.  Again PostgrSQL may have different values

This means you can simply link the reports table back to your os_table to get averages, counts etc very simply

```
SELECT AVG(value) AS AvgValue, COUNT(value) AS NumValues, R.report_name
FROM os_table AS T
JOIN Report_Periods AS R ON  T.datetime_>= R.report_start_date AND  T.datetime_<= R.report_end_date
GROUP BY R.report_name
```

Comment: Thank you Tom
This is indeed a fundamentally good way of solving the problem. But, with my level of experience in sql, I prefer to use this once I am better at it.
Thank you again :)